# How to add custom validation on w2ui?

Tags: w2ui

I've two fields ReasonDate and RegistrationDate. According to business logic RegistrationDate cannot be earlier than ReasonDate. I'm checking in 'onValidate' event handler of form like this:

```
onValidate: function(event) {
    var pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
    var reasonDt = new Date(w2ui.form.record.ReasonDate.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
    var registrationDt = new Date(w2ui.form.record.RegistrationDate.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));

    if (reasonDt > registrationDt) {
        $('#ReasonDate').w2tag('@TranslateText("accard_ReasonDateShouldLessThanRegDate")');
        //$('#ReasonDate').addClass('w2ui-error');
    }
},
```

and on button click I'm validating like this:

```
add: function () {
    $('#BudgOrgTin').removeClass('w2ui-error');
    var errors = w2ui.form.validate(true);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return;
    }
```

How to add correctly my error message so that when I validate form it returns my error too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this in the sources of w2ui:

```
onValidate: function(event) {
  var pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
  var reasonDt = new Date(w2ui.form.record.ReasonDate.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));
  var registrationDt = new Date(w2ui.form.record.RegistrationDate.replace(pattern, '$3-$2-$1'));

  if (reasonDt > registrationDt) {

     event.errors.push({field: this.get('RegistrationDate'), 
                        error: '@TranslateText("accard_ReasonDateShouldLessThanRegDate")'})

     // **no need for this anymore** w2ui does it for you
     // $('#ReasonDate').w2tag('@TranslateText("accard_ReasonDateShouldLessThanRegDate")');
     //$('#ReasonDate').addClass('w2ui-error');
  }
},
```